# how to show the data in Ui if i am getting data in console in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i have written one html file and corresponding controller logic for this page i am getting data in console but that data is not showing in my UI

```
<div id="panelDemo14" class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="NoticeController">


     <div class="panel-heading">Enter Notice here</div>
     <div class="panel-body">
        <tabset>

            <!-- SECOND TAB -->
            <tab heading="Notice List">

                      <div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="NoticeController "  >
     <div class="panel-body">
```

Displaying all notices. {{ gradeFilter }} {{ sectionFilter }}

```
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="box-placeholder">


                      <!-- START DATATABLE 1 -->




                                <div class="panel panel-default  {{ dataLoad }}">
                                                                        <div class="panel-heading">

                                                                             <a ng-mousedown="csv.generate()" ng-href="{{ csv.link() }}" download="test.csv" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-info">Export to CSV</a>
                                                                             <div ng-if="gradeFilter" class="panel-title">Classes</div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="table-responsive ">

                                                                           <table ng-table="table.tableParams" export-csv="csv" show-filter="true" class="table table-bordered table-striped">




                                                                               <tr ng-repeat="g in $data ">
                                                                                     <td data-title ="'Topic'" align="center" >{{g.noticeId}}</td>

                                                                                    <td data-title ="'Message'" align="center" >{{g.message}}</td>
                                                                                    <td data-title ="'Sender'" align="center" >{{ g.senderName    }} </td>
                                                                                    <td data-title ="'Date'" align="center" >{{ g.date | cmdate:'dd-MMM-yyyy' }}</td>
                                                                                    <td align="center"><a ui-sref="admin.viewEditnotice({nid : g.noticeId})">View </a></td>
                                                                                 </tr>

                                                                           </table>
                                                                        </div>
                              </div>


               </div>
           </div>



        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

and my controller file

```
enter code here/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
console.log('Notice loaded');

App.controller('NoticeController', ["$scope","$http","$stateParams","Notice","toaster","APISource",function($scope,$http,$stateParams,Notice,toaster,APISource) {
  'use strict';





 $http.get(APISource.currentApiPoint+"/app/notice")
        .success(function(data){

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

        })
        .error(function(data)
        {

        });
```

Comment: And how are we supposed to solve the problem just by knowing your comment , we need to know what code is written

Comment: can you provide your code? It's not possible to answer your question "it just doesn't work". :)

Comment: i have also added my code you can look out my code......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your AJAX response to controller model like this:

`$scope.$data = data`

Answer (score 1):

Define your data as, `$scope.mydata = data` and then in ng-repeat use, `g in mydata`